# Usage of "she herself" or "he himself"

Tags: etymology, redundancy

As I understand it, *he* and *him* are etymologically, and for purposes of grammar, different cases of the same word. If it's the same word, wouldn't it be sufficient to use *himself* alone—with maybe the redundancy reserved for emphasis?

Comment: *She herself* and *he himself* **are** emphatic: *She herself said she did it.* ...  that is, **she** said it, she accused herself, this is not something someone else said.

Comment: Repetition is a common form of emphasis, isn't it? Well, isn't it?

Comment: _He himself_ is very much like Latin _egomet_ lit 'I-me', an emphatic form of the first person pronoun. English doesn't have many morphological resources left, but the reflexive pronoun compounds _my/your/him/her/it/themself, our/your/themselves_ have the distinction of being the only English paradigm to still distinguish 2nd person singular (_yourself_) and plural (_yourselves_), to say nothing of the nonspecific indefinite _themself_ that is now widely used as the reflexive of ["singular _they_"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/June05Eye.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler I’m not sure that [Latin *‑met*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-met#Latin) is necessarily or strictly “me” despite its apparent 1p origin, in that it came to be used as a way of emphasizing other pronouns as well: *suamet, tutemet*. It was so frequently followed by the emphatic *ipse* that the [Vulgar Latin **metipse*, **metissimus*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Vulgar_Latin/metipsimus) gave rise to modern Romance *mismo, mesmo, même* and such, which when similarly pospositioned mean the same thing as *‑self* (ES *yo mismo, ella misma*; FR *moi-même, lui-même* etc).

Answer (score 3):

I would simply say, "Umm, yes." But that's flimsy. So I'll say, yes, it's often the case that *himself* is adequate by *itself*. (See?) And, of course, putting *he* and *himself* together can form an emphatic case.

But I also want to point out that the "he, himself" phrasing is also fundamental to a known logical fallacy, the bare assertion fallacy. Take a look at this slim yet informative article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipse_dixit

This leads to the sarcastic use of *He, himself, has said it* by which the validity of *his* statement is undermined by pointing out that the only basis for its supposed validity is that the speaker said it. This, then, is not an emphasis by repetition, but a refutation by mocking repetition.